# Kotliquery doesn't close postgresql connections

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, kotlin, hikaricp

I'm using Kotlin with the [kotliquery](https://github.com/seratch/kotliquery) jdbc framework

Just ran into a problem. I'm using a remote PostgreSQL database. After a bit of calling the database I get the following error `Failure: too many clients already`. Which is caused by 100 connections being `idle`.

I'm trying to create 1 point where I have to do the config. This is what I call my BaseDAO. The relevant code for that class looks like this:

```
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
import kotliquery.Session
import kotliquery.sessionOf
import javax.sql.DataSource

class BaseDAO {
    companion object {
        var url: String = "jdbc:postgresql://server.local:5432/myDatabase"
        var user: String = "postgres"
        var pass: String = "postgres"

        val config: HikariConfig = HikariConfig()

        private fun dataSource(): DataSource
        {
            var hikariConfig: HikariConfig =  HikariConfig();
            hikariConfig.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(url);
            hikariConfig.setUsername(user);
            hikariConfig.setPassword(pass);

            hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(5);
            hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
            hikariConfig.setPoolName("springHikariCP");

            hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.cachePrepStmts", "true");
            hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
            hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
            hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.useServerPrepStmts", "true");

            var dataSource: HikariDataSource  = HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);

            return dataSource;
        }

        @JvmStatic fun getSession(): Session {
            return sessionOf(dataSource())
        }
    }

}
```

And one of my DAO's:

```
class UserDAO {

    val toUser: (Row) -> User = { row ->
        User(
                row.int("id"),
                row.string("username"),
                row.string("usertype")
        )
    }

    fun getAllUsers(): List<User> {
        var returnedList: List<User> = arrayOf<User>().toList()
        using(BaseDAO.getSession()) { session ->

            val allUsersQuery = queryOf("select * from quintor_user").map(toUser).asList
            returnedList = session.run(allUsersQuery)
            session.connection.close() 
            session.close()
        }

        return returnedList
    }
}
```

After looking into Kotliquery's source code I realized the `session.connection.close()` and `session.close` wouldn't even be neccessary when using `using` (since it closes a `closable` which the retrieved `session` is.) but without them I got the same error. (had to restart postgresql database -- 100 idle connections).

I was wondering if there is an error in my code or if this is an error in Kotliquery?

*(also submitted github issue #6 but figured the community might be bigger than 24 people*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that each call to `BaseDAO.getSession()` creates new `HikariDataSource`. This means that every `Session` has effectively it's **own database connection pool**. To resolve that you need to maintain instance of `HikariDataSource` differently i.e.:

```
class BaseDAO {
    companion object {
        ...
        private val dataSource by lazy {
            var hikariConfig: HikariConfig =  HikariConfig();
            ...
            var dataSource: HikariDataSource  = HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);

            dataSource;
        }

        @JvmStatic fun getSession(): Session {
            return sessionOf(dataSource)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks, didn't work at first but had a different issue regarding another api calling my database :)